# Execute php when a button is clicked

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a contact form which is linked to `contact.php`. I've added a small captcha widget to the form. I know spam bots can still get this but it's just for learning purposes.

Anyways, I created 2 random numbers and user must type the corresponding answer in the textarea near it. The problem is that I cannot get PHP to run when submit is clicked to check if captcha is correct or not.

Sorry if the code is a little messed up but its only a simple form containing name, email and the message + a button.

P.S: `$total` is used only as it stopped chrome from displaying the confirm form resubmission message from being displayed when attempting to refresh.

**Update:**
First of all thanks for all the corrections, I am new to here.
Secondly it is only half-solved. This is because the captcha verification alert message is only being shown when I remove `contact.php` from `<form action="contact.php" method="post" name="contact_form">`. Apart from all this, since I am fairly new to web programming, is there any other programming language (best to use in this context) I can use so that I can create the captcha, check it and place a note like `Your captcha is incorrect` on top of the textbox(if captcha is incorrect) and prevent users from submitting form until the value is correct?

```
<?php
// init session to store captcha numbers
session_start() 
?>

<form action="contact.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
<div class="contact" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Contact Us For a Quote</h2>
        <div class="contact-info">
            <ul>
                <li class="first">
                    <div class="position">
                        <a class=" icon user"></a><input name="name"     type="text" class="text" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if     (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="dot">
                            <span> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="first">
                    <div class="position">
                        <a class=" icon email"></a><input name="email" type="text" class="text" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="dot">
                            <span> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                <li class="second">
                    <div class="position">
                        <a class=" icon msg"></a><textarea name="message" value="Your Message/request" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Message/request';}">Your Message/request</textarea>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="dot1">
                            <span> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class= "verification">
            <center>
                <?php
                $min = 1;
                $max = 7;
                $num1 = rand ($min, $max);
                do{
                    $num2 = rand ($min, $max);
                }while($num1 == $num2);
                // store captcha numbers to check them on submit
                $_SESSION['num1'] = $num1;
                $_SESSION['num2'] = $num2;
                echo $num1 . " + " . $num2 . " =";
                $total = $num1 + $num2;
                ?>
                <input name="ver" type="text" value="" onfocus="this.value = '';" size="2" maxlength="2">
            </center>
        </div>

        <center><input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit Request"></center>
        <?php
        // your form pass data through post, not get
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            //submit clicked
            $verification = $_POST['ver'];
            // check numbers on submit
            if($_SESSION['num1'] + $_SESSION['num2'] != $verification)
            {
                echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert("Incorrect verification code");</script>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Printscreen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Ca9.png

**contact.php contents**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "name@example.com";
$subject = "New Form Submission";
$finmsg = "A visitor has submitted a new request.\n\nName: $name\nEmail: $email\nMessage: $message";
mail ($to, $subject, $finmsg);
?>
```

Comment: You're actioning the form on contact.php, is that code snippet included in the contact.php file?

Comment: Show the code from `contact.php`.

Comment: I see you are using `$_GET` when your form says `$_POST`, also if your processing the form on the same page, put the php processing at the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $num1 and $num2 variables are not defined then your check captcha, because variable states are not saved between different requests.

You should use smth like sessions to preserve variable values. See comments in snippet below:

```
<?php
  // init session to store captcha numbers
  session_start() 
?>

<form action="contact.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <div class="contact" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Contact Us For a Quote</h2>
            <div class="contact-info">
                <ul>
                    <li class="first">
                        <div class="position">
                            <a class=" icon user"></a><input name="name" type="text" class="text" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}">
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="dot">
                                <span> </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="first">
                        <div class="position">
                            <a class=" icon email"></a><input name="email" type="text" class="text" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}">
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="dot">
                                <span> </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    <li class="second">
                        <div class="position">
                            <a class=" icon msg"></a><textarea name="message" value="Your Message/request" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Message/request';}">Your Message/request</textarea>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="dot1">
                                <span> </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class= "verification">
                <center>
                    <?php
                    $min = 1;
                    $max = 7;
                    $num1 = rand ($min, $max);
                    do{
                        $num2 = rand ($min, $max);
                    }while($num1 == $num2);
                    // store captcha numbers to check them on submit
                    $_SESSION['num1'] = $num1;
                    $_SESSION['num2'] = $num2;
                    echo $num1 . " + " . $num2 . " =";
                    $total = $num1 + $num2;
                    ?>
                    <input name="ver" type="text" value="" onfocus="this.value = '';" size="2" maxlength="2">
                </center>
            </div>

            <center><input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit Request"></center>
            <?php
            // your form pass data through post, not get
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                //submit clicked
                $verification = $_POST['ver'];
                // check numbers on submit
                if($_SESSION['num1'] + $_SESSION['num2'] != $verification)
                {
                    echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert("Incorrect verification code");</script>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Comment: Please add some definition why you wanted to do this ?